# Unhandled exception at an if statement in C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and in the following code snippet there occurs an exception at the if statement after fseek.

```
int load_filenew(char *filename, char **buffer)
{
    int size = 0;
    FILE *fp = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf(" fopen failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (size)
    {
        if (*buffer)
        {
            free(*buffer);
        }
        *buffer = 0;
        *buffer = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
        if (!*buffer)
        {
            printf(" malloc failed.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return 3;
        }
        memset(*buffer, 0, size + 1);
        fread(*buffer, size, 1, fp);
        (*buffer)[size] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return 2;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This function is called several times in the application but at some times unhandled exception is thrown at following line while loading a file

```
//exception code
if (size)
{
    if (*buffer)
```

Please help — what could be the possible cause and how to resolve it?

Comment: what is the error message? Please post it.

Comment: Can you include how you call the function - and in particular, what you do to ensure that *buffer == 0 or points to a valid buffer when it is called? The most likely source of error is that `buffer==NULL`, or otherwise not a valid pointer.

Comment: The line `*buffer = 0;` is superfluous.

Comment: It is possible that `buffer` is not 'initialized' to `NULL`. Such that `if(*buffer)` is `true` but `*buffer` does not point to a valid memory location and hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: @chris: Wrong, `"rb"` is perfectly acceptable.  See [C89 §4.9.5.3](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) or C99 §7.19.5.3.

Comment: What did you mean by the code segment if (*buffer)
        {
            free(*buffer);
        }

Comment: @Akhil - `*buffer` is a pointer to a string. Therefore if not NULL one could assume that it has previously been allocated. So the free will deallocate it.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, Oh, wow, sorry. I didn't see the part below. I just remembered something like this (I thought it was rb, but obviously not) that came up a few days ago and apparently only worked on MSVC'.

Comment: I think we cannot assume that so.Also what is the status(related to memory) of **buffer?

Comment: @akhil, we can assume that, but the assumption is based on the precondition that `buffer` points to a valid heap location allocated my `malloc`. This precondition has to be satisfied otherwise it could result in a seg-fault or other sort of runtime errors as in this case.

Comment: Before dereferencing the double pointer `buffer`, make sure `buffer` itself is valid!!

Comment: can you show the code where you call `load_filenew`?

Comment: at the beginning of the function, put a check `if(buf == NULL) return`. Also from next time onwards, `gcc -g code.c` will give a debug build and `gdb` will be able to show you what exactly is the problem

Comment: thanks to all of you , the issue seems that buffer is pointing to some non valid memory location. currently it is working fine by a slight modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not solving your problem directly but:

```
    if (*buffer)
    {
        free(*buffer);
    }
    *buffer = 0;
    *buffer = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
```

have you considered using `realloc()` instead?

```
    p = realloc(*buffer, size + 1);
    if ( p != NULL ) 
    { 
      *buffer = p; 
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems like `buffer` is probably set to `NULL` or some other invalid pointer and probably segfaults when you dereference it. It could also be your first call to `free` if the pointer is invalid. Ideally you need to show us the code that calls this function.

Also keep in mind it's bad form to call a matching `malloc` and `free` in different functions. Unless that function has only one purpose, to allocate a new structure or to free an existing one (In other words allocation of any resource should be done in the same function as deallocation of that same resource. The only exception is a function that composes more complex allocations and deallocations).

```
int load_filenew(char *filename, char **buffer)
{
    int size = 0;
    FILE *fp = 0;

    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf(" fopen failed.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (size)
    {
        *buffer = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
        if (!*buffer)
        {
            printf(" malloc failed.\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return 3;
        }
        memset(*buffer, 0, size + 1);
        fread(*buffer, size, 1, fp);
        (*buffer)[size] = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return 3;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for `In other words allocation of any resource should be done in the same function as deallocation of that same resource`